# input in elif and calling input outside statement. Problem: not defined

Tags: python

```
airlock = input("Has the air pressure equalised Y/N: ")
airlock = airlock.lower
if airlock == "n":
    print("They wait until the air pressure equalises.")
    airlock = input("Has the air pressure equalised Y/N: ");
elif airlock == "y":
    light = input("Does the airlock pressured light show green? Y/N");
else:
    airlock = input("Has the air pressure equalised Y/N: ");
light = light.lower
if light == "n":
    print("The air lock continues to pressurise.")
    light = input("Does the airlock pressured light show green? Y/N: ");
elif light == "y":
    print("The air lock is pressuresed.");
print("Corporal Alecks opens the inner airlock door and enters the moonbase with Commander Lorene")
print("Corporal Alecks takes Commander Lorene to the med bay")
print("Mission complete")
```

"light" input not defined when run. What should I do?

Tried running this code and it says that "light" is not defined

Comment: Hint: If `airlock == "n"`, then what does `light` equal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has a few errors:

1. It is not `lower` but instead `lower()`.
2. You are not checking if `light` is defined and simply calling it.
3. It looks you want to run the input forever until `airlock == y`. So use a `while` loop. Same for `light`.

Here's the fixed code:

```
airlock = input("Has the air pressure equalised Y/N: ").lower() # You can lower in one line
while airlock != "y": # Runs all the time if airlock not y
    if airlock == "n":
        print("They wait until the air pressure equalises.")
    airlock = input("Has the air pressure equalised Y/N: ");
else: # airlock == y
    light = input("Does the airlock pressured light show green? Y/N").lower(); # You can lower in one line
    while light != "y":
        if light == "n":
            print("The air lock continues to pressurise.")
        light = input("Does the airlock pressured light show green? Y/N: ");
    else:
        print("The air lock is pressuresed.");
        print("Corporal Alecks opens the inner airlock door and enters the moonbase with Commander Lorene")
        print("Corporal Alecks takes Commander Lorene to the med bay")
        print("Mission complete")
```

Also it is not necessary to use `;` in python.

Answer (score 0):

`lower` is a method. In order to lowercase a string, you have to write parentheses after it (`.lower()`). So change

```
airlock = airlock.lower
light = light.lower
```

to

```
airlock = airlock.lower()
light = light.lower()
```

Your code will now run as you intend. The problem was that `airlock` was set to neither `y` or `n`, but to the `lower` method, so neither the `if` or `elif` ran in the statement after.

Also, by the way Python does not have semi-colons at the end of lines.

Comment: They also expect it to ask an endless input until `airlock != "y"`.  Quite evident from what they are really trying to do. Also, if the `else` condition runs for `airlock` then you will still get the `light` is not defined error. This doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: What if I input `n`, then something else and then `y` the code would not function in this case.